# insert in one table automatically adds null to another table

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables namely question and answer table.

**Question Table Columns:
qid (primary key auto increment),
question,
date,
Answer,
ans_id (foreign key whos value will be qid),
answer**

This is what I want to do. I insert values in one table for instance question table and then  automatically the qid is insert into answer table column ans_id
For Example

I insert values

```
**qid => 1
question => 'This is question'
date => 'dd/mm/yy' (auto insert)**
```

by just entering in question table the answer table value should be automatically inserted like this

```
**ans_id => 1
answer => null**
```

I know this can be done easily in access but I am unable to do this in my sql phpmyadmin.I have also added foreign key constraint but it is not helping.Plz help

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look at triggers. You can INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE or almost anything else triggered by another INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: There are actual working examples in the provided link that do exactly what you want. Please make an effort yourself!

Answer (score 0):

**Table structure**

```
Question (qid, question, date)  --- qid (primary and Auto increment)
Answer(ans_id, answer, qid)   ---- ans_id (primary and auto increment) qid (foreign key)
```

Here you can do like:

```
// calling save to save values in DB
function save()
{
    // getting values from post
    // insert query to save values of question in Question table
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Question` (`question`, `date`) VALUES ('$question', NOW())");
    $last_inserted_question_id = mysql_insert_id(); // return last inserted id
    // again run insert query to insert value in answer table
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Answer` (`answer`, `qid`) VALUES (null , '$last_inserted_question_id')");
}
```

Else you can use concept of triggers that will run automatically query for insert in Answer table when ever you insert something in question table.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS testTrigger;
CREATE TRIGGER testTrigger 
BEFORE INSERT ON Question
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  // insert query for answer table
END;
```

I Hope will help you!

Comment: this might get difficult when lot of people are entring data into this.

Comment: @Umerm: Then you can go for trigger that is pre-executed query. And will run automatically.

Comment: can u give here an example of my table just for understanding.I would be very thankful to u.

Comment: DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS testTrigger;
CREATE TRIGGER testTrigger 
AFTER INSERT ON Question
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
// insert query for answer table
END;

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx

You can go for stored procedure also. This is one good example.
If I helped u and given some idea how to solve please vote for my answer.

Comment: DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS testTrigger; CREATE TRIGGER testTrigger AFTER INSERT ON Question FOR EACH ROW BEGIN // 
INSERT INTO `ad_answer`(`ans_id`, `ans`) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2]) END

tell me what should i write in value-1 ? Here i wanted to assign qid

Comment: In triggers you can't pass parameter as like functions.
Please go with mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx
So, while writing your own procedure you can pass IN parameter i.e. ques_id in your case. And can write insert query in procedure.
Given you good link

It will be like
Insert query for Question
// will return Ques_id inserted 
Call procedure pass question id and will execute insert query for answer table. Remember you need not to pass value for column which is primary and has auto increment.